# Ephemeral tasks on Marathon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, mesosphere, marathon

Before hand let me say that I'm new to Mesosphere stack. I am trying to migrate an existing Rails application deployment to Mesos and I'm successful so far, but currently I'm on the middle of running migrations and seeds (through Rake tasks) and I don't see a pretty way to get it done since those tasks are ephemeral and they don't match quite Marathon's idea. How should I proceed?

Comment: One-off tasks are currently a feature request in Marathon. You could mention your use case in the GitHub Issue to put in your vote: https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/344

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use [Chronos](https://github.com/mesosphere/chronos) to run a task "Now" that is expected to complete at some point.

Marathon is targeted at long-running services that should always keep running.

Comment: Thanks @Adam, Chronos seems to be a good choice, FYI Marathon is working on adding this feature too.

Answer (score 0):

Recent development has included the "Job" capability via Metronome (Chronos replacement) or you can also use [Eremetic](https://github.com/klarna/eremetic) framework for one-off tasks.