# How to run a one-off task with Apache Mesos/Marathon?

Tags: mesos, marathon

I'm trying to run a one-off task with Marathon. I'm able to get the task container running, but after the task command completes, marathon runs another task, and so on. How can I prevent Marathon from running more than one task/command?

Or, if this is not possible with Marathon, how can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a hack you can kill a marathon task at the end, as suggested here: https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/344#issuecomment-86697361

As rukletsov already mentioned - Marathon is desigend for long-running tasks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26647789/1047843

If Chronos doesn't fit in your situation you can use Jenkins with Mesos plugin: https://github.com/jenkinsci/mesos-plugin

Or you can try to talk with Mesos directly and write you own framework: http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/app-framework-development-guide/

In my opinion the two easiest options would be Chronos and Jenkins.

Comment: Plus 1 for Chronos. That is a lot of different answers.

Comment: Regarding the suicide hack by using the DELETE API with curl, what can we do if we're using a container and it doesn't have curl installed?
Copying/mounting the binary may not work as it may depend on target OS.

Answer (score 6):

Marathon [is designed](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon) for long running services, which means it will restart the task once it enters a terminal state. Depending on the nature of your task, you may want to take a look at other Mesos frameworks, e.g. [Chronos](https://github.com/mesos/chronos). If you want to start a single task, you can use `mesos-execute` tool which accompanies Mesos.

Comment: Is it possible to run a service with Chronos now (not scheduled) and once?

Comment: I'm not a Chronos expert, but it should understand ISO8601 fine. Try to pass "R1/..." as a value for the "schedule" key in the job description.

Answer (score 5):

Since the question was answered a new framework called Eremetic has been developed for marathon that allows you to run one off tasks.

https://github.com/klarna/eremetic

Answer (score 0):

@Sander Smits: How @rukletsov wrote you can use the repeating intervals ISO8601 to execute services only one time. After the execution the job will be automatically disabled by chronos. Use"R0/.." (0 repetition) for schedule setting.